# How to show/hide images using vertical nav

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to show/hide images using vertical nav but I lack knowlige in Jquery, can somebody help?

I already have jquery for switching between active states in vertical nav:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.vertical__menu-item').click(function () {
        $('.vertical__menu-item').removeClass("vertical__menu-item--active ");
        $(this).addClass("vertical__menu-item--active ");
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dh8Lucjk/1/

Comment: when you say *using vertical nav*, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding ID tags to your vertical nav items to make it easier. You could so something like this:

```
<ul class="vertical__menu">
                            <li>
                                <a class="vertical__menu-item vertical__menu-item--active" href="#" id="link1">Truck Route</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="vertical__menu-item" href="#" id="link2">Location Map</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="vertical__menu-item" href="#" id="link3">Major Retailers Map</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Then your jquery could utilize these ID's to determine which image to show:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.location__content-img-wrapper').hide();
    $('#location-img-1').show();
    $('.vertical__menu-item').click(function () {
        $('.vertical__menu-item').removeClass("vertical__menu-item--active ");
        $(this).addClass("vertical__menu-item--active ");
        $('.location__content-img-wrapper').hide();
        $('#location-img-'+$(this).attr('id').substr(-1)).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Reps this works, but is there a way to have the only first picture shown on load and not all 3 and then to hide the others that are not clicked?

Comment: I've updated the code I posted to function that way! Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are doing wrong. it will helpfull for you.

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
});

$("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
```